# Count XElements Grouped by Parent using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Consider the following XML...

```
<stock>
    <dealer>
        <dealername>Dealer 1</dealername>
        <vehicle>
            <stockID>11111</stockID>
            ...
        </vehicle>
        <vehicle>
            <stockID>22222</stockID>
            ...                
        </vehicle>
        <vehicle>
            <stockID>33333</stockID>
            ...
        </vehicle>
    </dealer>
    <dealer>
        <dealername>Dealer 2</dealername>
        <vehicle>
            <stockID>44444</stockID>
            ...
        </vehicle>
        <vehicle>
            <stockID>55555</stockID>
            ...                
        </vehicle>
    </dealer>
</stock>
```

I need to parse this XML and insert db records containing...

```
Dealer Name
Count of Vehicles for that Dealer Name
```

...so for the above example this would be...

```
DealerName    Count of Vehicles
Dealer 1      3
Dealer 2      2
```

I'm working with the following LINQ code but I can't seem to get the result I need...

```
// count the number of vehicles by dealer name
var qry = from dealer in downloadedXml.Descendants("dealername")
          group dealer by dealer.Value
          into grp
          select new {
             DealerName = grp.Key,
             Count = grp.Select(x => x.Descendants("vehicle")).Distinct().Count()
          };

foreach (var row in qry.OrderBy(x => x.DealerName)) {
    // do db insert
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
var result = from d in doc.Descendants("dealer")
    select new
    {
        Name = d.Element("dealername").Value,
        Total = d.Descendants("vehicle").Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this way

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\test\r.xml");

var data =
   doc.Descendants("stock").Elements("dealer")
      .Select(
              a =>
                  new
                     {
                       DealerName = a.Element("dealername").Value,
                       VehiclesCount = a.Descendants("vehicle").Count()
                     });

foreach (var d in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.DealerName);
    Console.WriteLine(d.VehiclesCount);
}
```